# free mutex issue

Tags: c++, mutex

Hey all, would appreciate any help with a little problem im having. Basically my program works fine but does not pass all the required tests. Apparently the problem is not doing one of the following:

- that you join all the threads which you create
- that you destroy all the mutices which you init
- that you unlock all mutices which you lock

can anybody see where ive gone wrong? Would very much appreciate any help, thankyou

```
   #include "counter.h"

/* ============================================================================
 * File-global variables
 * ========================================================================== */
static int ncounters = 0;
static struct counter *counters = NULL;

static int nthreads = 0;
static int *ninstructions = NULL;
static struct instruction **instructions = NULL;


/* ============================================================================
 * Operations
 * ========================================================================== */
static void
decrement(long long *n) {
    *n = *n-1;
}

static void
increment(long long *n) {
    *n = *n+1;
}

static void
mult2(long long *n) {
    long long s = 2;
    long long t = *n;
    long long q = t*s;
    *n = q;
}


/* ============================================================================
 * Helper functions
 * ========================================================================== */

int
quit(void) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<nthreads; ++i) {
        free (instructions[i]);
    }
    free (instructions);
    for (i=0; i<ncounters; ++i) {
        pthread_mutex_t *my = &(counters[i].mylock);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(my);
    }
    free (counters);
    free (ninstructions);
    return 0;
}

/* ============================================================================
 * Thread function
 * ========================================================================== */
static void *
worker_thread(void *arg) {
    int t = *((int*)arg);
    int l;
    for (l = 0; l<ninstructions[t]; ++l) {
        int y;
        struct instruction* curr = &instructions[t][l];
        pthread_mutex_lock(&curr->counter->mylock);
        for (y=0; y<curr->repetitions; ++y) {
            long long *g = &curr->counter->counter;
            (curr->work_fn)(g);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&curr->counter->mylock);
    }

    return NULL;
}


/* ============================================================================
 * Main function
 * ========================================================================== */
int
main(void) {
    if (scanf("%d", &ncounters) != 1 || ncounters < 1) {
        printf("error\n");
        return quit();
    }
    counters = (struct counter*)malloc(ncounters*sizeof(struct counter));


    if (scanf(" %d", &nthreads) != 1 || nthreads < 1) {
        printf("error\n");
        return quit();
    }
    ninstructions = (int *)malloc(nthreads*sizeof(int));
    instructions = (struct instruction**)malloc(nthreads*sizeof(struct instruction*));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<nthreads; ++i) {

        if (scanf(" %d", &ninstructions[i]) != 1) {
            printf("error\n");
            return quit();
        }
        instructions[i] = (struct instruction*)malloc(ninstructions[i]*sizeof(struct instruction));
        int k;
        for (k=0; k<ninstructions[i]; ++k) {
            int c, r;
            char f;
            if (scanf(" %d %c %d", &c, &f, &r) != 3 || c>ncounters-1) {
                printf("error\n");
                return quit();
            }
            struct instruction* curr = &instructions[i][k];
            struct counter* currcp = &counters[c];
            pthread_mutex_init (&currcp->mylock, NULL);
            curr->counter = currcp;
            curr->repetitions = r;
            switch(f) {
                case 'I': 
                    curr->work_fn = increment;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    curr->work_fn = decrement;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    curr->work_fn = mult2;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("error\n");
                    return quit();
            }
        }
    }
    int w;
    pthread_t threadIDs[nthreads];
    int args[nthreads];
    for (w=0; w<nthreads; ++w) {
        args[w] = w;
        pthread_create(&threadIDs[w], NULL, worker_thread, (void *) &args[w]);
    }
    int u;
    for (u=0; u<nthreads; ++u) {
        pthread_join(threadIDs[u], NULL);   
    }
    int d;
    for (d=0; d<ncounters; ++d) {
        printf("%lld\n", counters[d].counter);
    }
    return quit();
}
```

and the data structure

```
#ifndef __COUNTER_H__
#define __COUNTER_H__

#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* counter data structure */ 
struct counter {
    pthread_mutex_t mylock;
   long long counter;            /* to store counter */
};

/* counter value */
struct instruction {
   struct counter *counter;      /* pointer to counter */
   int repetitions;              /* number of repetitions  */
   void (*work_fn)(long long *); /* function pointer to work function */
};

#endif
```

yes sorry I thought it might be possible without the format:

```
<number of counters>
<number of threads>
<instruction-sequence>
<instruction-sequence>
....
<number of instructions>
<instruction>
<instruction>
....
```

so for each instruction sequence you have a list of instructions that are performed by each thread on one or more counters.
i.e. the input:

```
2
2
1
0 I 10
2
1 D 10
1 2 2
```

will yield result:

```
10
-40
```

(there are only three instruction types: increment (I), decrement (D), muliply by 2 (2)
where an instruction is of format:

```
<counter> <function> <repitition>
```

does that make sense?

Comment: Care to share useful input? It's kind of hard to make up numbers randomly from your source

Comment: problem is the testing input isnt disclosed so I have no idea what test im failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like you are joining all threads you create, and unlocking all mutices that you lock -- that part is fairly straightforward.

Looking at the second condition, however, there seems to be no obvious correlation between the creation and destruction of mutices.

You are calling `pthread_mutex_init` once per instruction, whereas you are calling `pthread_mutex_destroy` once per counter. I don't see any guarantee that the number of instructions equals the number of counters.

I would imagine you want one mutex per counter. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to be initting a single mutex per instruction. You probably want an initialisation routine which inits a mutex for each counter, to mirror your `quit` routine which destroys a mutex per counter.

Comment: yes I think youve got it, as you can (and probably will) have more instructions than counters. Ive now looped through each counter in the array and initialized the mutexes. Thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: Thanks. If you find that this solves your problem, please tick it off by clicking the white tick next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

with my own input

```
10
3
2
1 I 3
2 D 4
2
3 2 5
4 2 6
2
5 I 7
6 D 8
```

output was

```
$ ./t.exe < i
0
3
-4
0
0
7
-8
0
0
0
```

Using your input I got your expected result. What is the question?

### Update

> problem is the testing input isnt disclosed so I have no idea what test im failing

In that case, make unit test inputs and

- be sure to touch the edge cases (boundary conditions)
- run them under valgrind if this is linux; That way you'll be notified if anything is leaked.

Comment: does valgrind pick up mutex memory though? It came up with no leaks when I checked it yesterday? Ill have another go now, thanks.

Comment: It will indirectly since a mutext will also take up some memory. Also, you could use --tool=helgrind to see what sanity checks it mutters